# Approaches to versioning data stored in Redis by date

Tags: redis, data-modeling, key-value-store

In an application which persists the `fontSize` and `fontColor` that a user sets, what approach should be take to model the time series?
To elaborate, the user sets FontSize and FontColour at first run. Then during the course of their use of the application they may modify these properties. I want to keep the timestamp for when they change and also have the ability to query by this timestamp. I am looking for different approaches to modelling this data in Redis? If you can point to any data modelling literature, that'll be helpful too.

My thoughts were to use a Hashset and RPUSH the latest setting for a user to a list. But I am at a loss at the querying part when the only two parameters are userId and date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you want to store timeseries in Redis, your best bet would be to use Sorted Sets with the members' scores set as the epoch value. That would provide you with trivial date ranges via the use of `Z[REV]RANGEBYSCORE`.

As for your question, while using a Hash to store these settings is perfectly doable, you should offset that with the cost of keeping another key (both in terms of the memory footprint as well as the extra read/writes that its maintenance requires). If all you're after is storing the size/color tuple, I recommend embedding that in the Sorted Set's member value. As an example, consider the following:

```
ZADD settings:9876 12345678 "12345678:12px:red"
```

The above demonstrates storing the settings for userId 9876 for the (made up) timestamp 12345678. The member's value is a made up from concatenating the size and color values along with the timestamp to ensure uniqueness (remember that a [Sorted] Set's members have to be unique).